# Python boto3 parameterized queries with Athena

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-athena

I cant seem to find the document on how to pass execution parameters to Athena using boto3.  I did find how to do it using aws cli, like so:

```
aws athena start-query-execution 
--query-string "SELECT * FROM table WHERE x = ? AND y = ?"
--query-execution-context "Database"="default" 
--result-configuration "OutputLocation"="s3://..."
--execution-parameters "1" "2"
```

Is there a way to do the same using boto3 with something like:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client(
            "athena",
            aws_access_key_id=XXX,
            aws_secret_access_key=YYY,
            region_name=ZZZ,
)
response = client.start_query_execution(
            QueryString="SELECT * FROM table WHERE x = ? AND y = ?",
            QueryExecutionContext={"Database": "default"},
            ResultConfiguration={"OutputLocation": "s3://..."},
            WorkGroup=self._kwargs.get('workgroup'),
)
```

Is it possible to do it with boto3 without using prepared statements?

Comment: `ExecutionParameters` as said in the docs https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Client.start_query_execution

Comment: Weird.  Thats what I tried before and got `Unknown parameter in input: "ExecutionParameters", must be one of: QueryString, ClientRequestToken, QueryExecutionContext, ResultConfiguration, WorkGroup`.  Let me check my version

Comment: Nevermind.  I had boto3 1.21.16...after upgrading to 1.24.42 it works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `awswrangler` to do it very simply:

```
import awswrangler as wr
df = wr.athena.read_sql_query(
    sql="SELECT * FROM table WHERE x=:x; AND y=:y;",
    params={"x": "'x_value'", "y": "'y_value'"}
)
```

To read more how the `read_sql_query` function works and list of params: https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs/awswrangler.athena.read_sql_query.html